# Delegate file downloading to external function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How I can delegate file downloading to external function by file's MIME-type via Chrome API?
For example, I want to download in my Chrome extension to memory all .exe-files via XMLHTTPRequest and count hash sums of this files for security checking. Then I want to save file to disk, if it's safe.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/rndme/download to manually trigger a download from JS

Comment: @dandavis it's ok, but how I can hijack user's downloads on different sites?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `webRequest` API and `downloads` API.

Since your question is quite broad, I'll show a broad overview of what I have in mind.

1. Set up `webRequest` to intercept all requests that end in `.exe` and do not originate from your extension.
2. Cancel the request, perhaps show your own page instead that explains that the file is being checked.
3. XHR the file yourself (take note of all required headers to replicate the request, which can, again, be set with `webRequest`).
4. Check the file; if it's okay, you can trigger a "download" of it with `chrome.downloads`.

This is a high-level overview and this may have issues; but such is the scope of your question.